# Bootstrap columns to rows

Tags: razor, bootstrap-4

I have this loop to display in html page.

```
foreach (var item in Model.Ratio)
        {
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="R" value="@item" /> @item
                </label>
            </div>
        }
```

this displays

col1   col2

col3   col4

col5   col6

but i need to display it in top to bottom (instead of left to right) format how to achieve this

col1  col4

col2  col5

col3  col6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similar question here: [Can I alter the way Bootstrap places columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083332/can-i-alter-the-way-bootstrap-places-columns)

The only way is using the [order classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#order-classes) which are difficult to calculate inside the loop, or CSS 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks that saved a lot of my time.